# Can't archive iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I'm trying to upload an app to App Store, for that I'm following [this guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dbabzWVvcvE), but when I try to build my app for distribution I can't

[image]

I know I have a valid provisioning profile for distribution, or at least I think so:
[image]

What is wrong in my app?

I changed some few things, here are the changes:
[image]

Comment: what's the error you're getting  ?

Comment: Also, where does the problem occur? Is it when you build the archive or when you try to upload it to Apple? If the latter, did you try to validate your build?

Comment: As you can see in first image, I don't have the option to build for distribution. I get no errors. What I want is build for distribution, but don't know why it doesn't give me the choice to

Comment: It is pretty clear you haven't set the code signing up properly and the provisioning profiles up properly. Check your first image, `Code Signing Identity > Release > Any iOS SDK` is set to `iOS Developer` this needs to be `iOS Distribution` you have everything the wrong way round, `Debug` should be `iOS Developer` not `iOS Distribution`. And under `Provisioning Profiles` it says `None` so you have no provisioning profiles set at all.

Comment: I found that bundle identifier was wrong, anyway, I still have same problem

Comment: @Popeye Provisioning Profile set to "None" is no problem.  Actually, I think it is badly named.  It seems to mean "Auto" instead (i.e. it will choose a provisioning profile it finds that matches the signing identity).  Anyway that video is 3 years old, so disregard it.  You just need to go to Product -> Archive.

Comment: It finalyy works! Thank you all!! @borrrden, your tip made it all faster! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Under the Provisioning Profile, select your profile (put it only under release), and under Code Signing Identity, you should have iOS distribution selected for both options, which should get the description from your distribution profile if everything is ok.

Note that you need to have the private key used to create the certificate which was used to create the distribution profile on your local machine as well.